# Domain registrar transfering

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration

In 2004 I registered a domain name when I opened an account with DiscountASP.NET. I presume my domain registration was handled by a reseller. A domain tools who is search shows that registration services are provided by Znode LLC. I changed hosting companies and need to change DNS servers to point to my new hosting company but I have no idea how to do that. There is no control panel I can access. Ideally I would like to transfer registrar's. I emailed Znode support but I have not received any response. I called and left a message and they have not called back.

My new hosting company wants an EPP authorization code in order to transfer my domain. I guess I need to get it from Znode LLC. Anyone have any ideas on how I might go about transferring my domain over to a new registrar?

The domain name has not expired and is currently active.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look into filing a transfer dispute if ZNode continues to be unresponsive. Talk to the registrar you want to transfer the domain name to to find out what their policy\process is and if they can provide assistance. Here's some info:

http://www.icann.org/en/udrp/#tdrp

http://www.icann.org/en/dndr/tdrp/approved-providers.htm

http://www.icann.org/en/registries/listing.html

Comment: OP: If you go this route, just be aware that it isnt cheap,as filing a UDRP, etc has quite a few fees associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Call again. I suggest calling the Sales number (US: 888.755.5541) if they don't answer the support number. Call during normal business hours, be very polite, and accept that they probably have several hoops you'll have to jump through in order to unlock the domain and get the EPP code.